# row items against each bars in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have plotted like below,

```
df1
Out[90]: 
     feature  OnePlus 2r  iPhone 6s Plusr  OnePlus 2  iPhone 6s Plus
0      Price     23000.0          80000.0   0.287500        1.000000
1     Length       151.8            158.2   0.959545        1.000000
2     Breath        74.9             77.9   0.961489        1.000000
3  Thickness         9.9              7.3   1.000000        0.737374

ax = df1[['OnePlus 2','iPhone 6s Plus']].plot(kind='bar', title ="Lesser the Better",
          figsize=(15,10),legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel(df1.feature,fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("%",fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[image]
How could I get price, length,.. against each bar instead of xlabel.

Is there a way without `set_index('feature')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to do something like

```
ax.set_xticklabels(df1.feature,fontsize=12)
```

to replace the indexes 0, 1, 2,3 with the feature corresponding with your bar-pairs?

[image]